# Details from a Proof that a Tournament has Property $S_k$

Tags: probability, graph-theory, asymptotics, exponential-function

(Edit: While the context is not central to my question, I decided to include it anyway to make the question a little more searchable.)

Some technical details are omitted from a theorem in Alon and Spencer's *The Probabilistic Method*.

A tournament on $n$ players is said to have property $S_k$ if, for any selection of $k$ players, there is another player that beats them all. The theorem states that a tournament has this property provided 
$$
\binom{n}{k}(1 - 2^{-k})^{n-k} < 1.
$$

Let $f(k)$ denote the smallest $n$ satisfying the inequality above (as a function of $k$). In order to find an upper bound on $f(k)$, the author makes the following replacements:

$$
\binom{n}{k} \leq \left(\frac{en}{k}\right)^k
$$
and
$$
(1 - 2^{-k})^{n-k} \leq e^{-(n-k)/2^k}.
$$

I believe the implication is now to write $n$ as a function of $k$ given that $n$ satisfies
$$
\left(\frac{en}{k}\right)^k e^{-(n-k)/2^k} < 1.
$$

How can I isolate $n$ in this expression? The details are omitted, but the author states
$$
n \geq k^2 2^k (\ln 2) (1 + o(1)),
$$
so
$$
f(k) \leq k^2 2^k (\ln 2) (1 + o(1)).
$$

Comment: I'm not sure that the implication you've written is correct, since using the two inequalities provided may in fact increase the product above 1.

Comment: @forallepsilon I did not explain it well. For fixed $k$, if $n$ is chosen large enough to ensure $\left(\frac{en}{k}\right)^k e^{-(n-k)/2^k} < 1$, then it is also large enough to ensure $\binom{n}{k}(1 - 2^{-k})^{n-k} < 1$ since $
\binom{n}{k} \leq \left(\frac{en}{k}\right)^k
$
and
$
(1 - 2^{-k})^{n-k} \leq e^{-(n-k)/2^k}.
$

Comment: If $\left(\frac{en}{k}\right)^k e^{-(n-k)/2^k} < 1$ then either $n < k/e$ or $n \approx \infty$, so it's not clear to me at all where $n \lessapprox k^2 2^k$ comes from.  Unless the inequality at the end should be $\gtrapprox$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the $\leq$ at the end should be $\geq$.

Since the function on the left-hand side is unimodal and is zero when $n=0$ and $n=\infty$, the inequality

$$
\left(\frac{en}{k}\right)^k e^{-(n-k)/2^k} < 1
$$

is satisfied in two intervals of the form $n \in [0,a) \cup (b,\infty)$.  Let's consider $=$ instead of $<$ for simplicity.  Rearranging a little yields

$$
n^k e^{-n/2^k} = \left(\frac{k}{e}\right)^k e^{-k/2^k},
$$

and on taking $k^\text{th}$ roots we get

$$
n e^{-n/(k2^k)} = \frac{k}{e} e^{-1/2^k}.
$$

Now let $n = k2^k m$, so that, upon multiplying through by $-k^{-1} 2^{-k}$,

$$
-m e^{-m} = -2^{-k} e^{-1-1/2^k}.
$$

We therefore have

$$
m = -W\left(-2^{-k}e^{-1-1/2^k}\right),
$$

where $W$ is the Lambert W function.  If we choose the branch $W = W_0$ then we obtain the interval endpoint $a$ defined above, and if we choose $W = W_{-1}$ we obtain the endpoint $b$.

Specifically, since $n = k 2^k m$ we have

$$
a = -k2^k W_0\left(-2^{-k}e^{-1-1/2^k}\right).
$$

Now $W_0(x) = x + O(x^2)$ as $x \to 0$, so

$$
\begin{align}
a &= -k2^k \left(-2^{-k}e^{-1-1/2^k}\right) + O(k2^{-k}) \\
&= k/e + O(k2^{-k})
\end{align}
$$

as $k \to \infty$.  Similarly, $W_{-1}(x) = \log(-x) + O\Bigl(\log(-\log(-x))\Bigr)$ as $x \to 0^-$, so

$$
\begin{align}
b &= -k2^k \left[\log\left(2^{-k}e^{-1-1/2^k}\right) + O(\log k)\right] \\
&= k^2 2^k \log2 + O(k 2^k\log k)
\end{align}
$$

as $k \to \infty$.

In other words, if

$$
\left(\frac{en}{k}\right)^k e^{-(n-k)/2^k} < 1
$$

then either

$$
0 \leq n < \frac{k}{e}\left(1+O(2^{-k})\right)
$$

or

$$
n > k^2 2^k \log 2 \left(1+O\left(\frac{\log k}{k}\right)\right)
$$

as $k \to \infty$.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Now that I have added context, you'll see that $n > k$ was implied. I apologize if that omission made your work more difficult.